# Concurrency problem with Coroutines and Socket Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, java.util.concurrent, coroutinescope

I have a chat application which of course works with Sockets. So i have build a SocketManager where i have the callbacks and the sendMethod from the `implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-websocket-client:2.14'` library

```
override fun sendMessage(text: String) {
    println("## SEND: $text")
    webSocket?.let {
        it.sendText(text)
    }
}


override fun onTextMessage(websocket: WebSocket?, message: String?) {
        super.onTextMessage(websocket, message)
        println("## RECEIVED: Something received")

        try {
            flowSocketHandler.webSocketEventResolver(s, message) {
                sendMessage(it)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

When a new text comes from Socket the FlowSocketHandler resolves the type of message and calls the proper handler to handle the message. For example, FileHandler for File messages, MEssageHandler for simple messages, VideoHandler for video call messages.

```
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())


override fun webSocketEventResolver(server: Server, message: String, socketCallback: (message: String) -> Unit) {
        scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val json = JSONObject(message)
                when(Enums.SocketResponses.toSocketEvent(json)) {

                    Enums.SocketResponses.MESSAGE_RECEIVED -> messagesHandler.onMessageReceived(server, json.fromJson(), true, socketCallback)

                    Enums.SocketResponses.FILE_PART_RECEIVED -> filesHandler.onFilePartReceived(server, json.fromJson(), socketCallback)

                    else -> {}
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, the philopsophy of downloading an incoming File message, is that

1. I have an incoming Text message that says "Hey, you have to download a file that consists of 1000 parts" which calls the MESSAGE_RECEIVED
2. I send 1000 socket messages requesting each part accordingly
3. I receive each part from Socket and handle it which calls the FILE_PART_RECEIVED

As you can see above, all this is taking place in a `scope` CoroutineScope

All this is taking place inside the FilesHandler

```
class FilesHandlerImpl(private val appContext: Context): FilesHandler, KoinComponent {

private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + SupervisorJob())

override suspend fun onFileHeaderReceived(
        server: Server,
        receiver: ReceiveNewMessage,
        isFromSocket: Boolean,
        socketCallback: ((message: String) -> Unit)?
    ) {
          
   scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {    
       // Do some checks and start send requests for each part
       println("## Time header message ${receiver.fileHash}")
       pendingList.forEach { p ->
           socketCallback?.invoke(requestFilePart(p))
       }

      // So here in the Log i see
      // ## Send {json for each part}
   }
}



// Take the part and create a file
override suspend fun onFilePartReceived(
        server: Server,
        receiver: FilePartRcv,
        socketCallback: (message: String) -> Unit
    ) {
   scope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
       println("## File part received ${receiver.filePart.segment}")
       filesRepository.createAndWriteFilePart(server, receiver)
       filesRepository.updateFilePartStatus(server, receiver, FILE_PART_RECEIVED)

       if (complete) {
          // Do stuff
       }
   } 

   // So here in every part we receive we see in the Log
   // ## File part received 1
   // ## File part received 4
   // ## File part received 2
   // ## File part received 6
   // ## File part received 9
   ......
}

}
```

The problem is the Following.
While the client sends requests for the File parts (So Log is full of ## SEND {...}) meanwhile the Socket callback `onTextMessage` is called so i see also `## RECEIVED: Something received`.
Those callbacks are the incoming File Parts. So i should also see the `## File part received X`. But i don't see any of those UNTIL the Send loop finishes. Then suddenly i see all the `## File part received X`.

What i did, is to remove the `scope` from `onFileHeaderReceived` and `onFilePartReceived` and seems to play a bit smoother.

Can anybody explain me why is that happening?

Answer (score 0):

scope.launch starts a job asynchronously. it returns a Job that you can hold onto and cancel on await.

If you just want to ensure the job happens on the IO Dispatcher, then you probably want withContext instead.  This will be blocking so operations will happen sequentially.

```
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
...
}
```

Dispatchers.Main will typically be single threaded also, so forming a queue as you suggest.  You could use Dispatchers.IO or Default to have concurrency.

https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-main.html

> A coroutine dispatcher that is confined to the Main thread operating with UI objects. Usually such dispatchers are single-threaded.

Also suspend isn't needed is it just calls scope.launch, since that isn't a suspending function.

Comment: My question is: Does the fact that both functions have the ```scope.launch``` inside makes them stop and entering some kind of queue that makes Receive wait for the Send to finish?

Comment: Yep - good point.  Main will be single threaded.